# Issue regarding Facebook permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'll be needing some help regarding the Facebook permissions. Actually, I have defined a permission set on my facebook developer account under permissions and setup an application as well. I would like my ios application to pull permissions (On Login) that are specified under my account. I know I can use iOS or FB SDK 3.5.1 in my application (which I am using) but I don't want to specify permissions set on device, Just want to save version submissions of my application on store, don't want to keep this on client side. I know how to achieve permissions etc on iOS device as well which I have been using since Facebook 2.0.

So, is there a way using which application should pull permissions from the application ID (developer account) instead of specifying the permission set on the client (iOS).

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to think in reverse direction but this is not possible to achieve.

Permissions are never attached to any app, we specify permission so we can use those explore more using that appID.

Means there is nothing as such permissions for appID, appID & permissions are both different thing.

For Eg: I have created an app to see my details on Facebook. In order to achieve it we are not required to configure my appId on facebook. So its only us(the developers) who know what user can do with Facebook using that FBID.

So we just ask permissions separatly.